# What is the difference between cave spiders and regular spider loot?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

It seems that killing cave spiders is easier than killing regular spiders to me. Is there a difference in the loot bonuses (mob spawners, mob crushers) or are they generally the same thing just in different areas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Minecraft wiki they do drop exactly the same thing. Their loot includes the following:

- 0-2 String
- 0-1 Spiders Eye
- 5 Experience

However, cave spiders have 12 points (6 hearts) of HP whereas spiders have 16 points (8 hearts), yet cave spiders are still poisonous. This is why it may seem easier to kill cave spiders.

Comment: Guess that makes cave spiders a better option for mob farms since they die quicker than normal spiders.

Comment: Indeed, It's just the poison and their size that can be quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

a cave spider is smaller than the regular spider and both will only attack you in Survival mode but never in Creative mode. They both drop 5 experience points and will only attack in the day if you hit it first.

Answer (score 0):

The spider is bigger and easier to kill whilst the cave spider smaller and easier because they have 2 hearts left both poisonous both will not attack you in daylight unless hit cave spiders will spawn  in spawnners they both drop 5 exp.drops same things and that’s most of the thing I know thanks of you have a question you can ask for the next one pls give me an upvote if I see one upvote I’ll be happy one pls thx love you guys bye

Comment: If you’re new like me sign in as a guest or login to comment or post and you can respond here thx I’m probably gonna confuse you hope this helps